# Qt qOverload - undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to learn to use **QComboBox**, I tried to compile a chunk of code from https://zetcode.com/gui/qt5/widgets/ but I always get the same error message “**use of undeclared identifier 'qOverload'** ”
I red all I can find about it on the net, but nothing helped.

I'm using Qt Creator 5.15 and C++11.

combobox.h :

```
#pragma once

#include <QWidget>
#include <QComboBox>
#include <QLabel>

class ComboBoxEx : public QWidget {

  Q_OBJECT

  public:
    ComboBoxEx(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

  private:
    QComboBox *combo;
    QLabel *label;
};
```

combobox.cpp :

```
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include "combobox.h"

ComboBoxEx::ComboBoxEx(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent) {

  QStringList distros = {"Arch", "Xubuntu", "Redhat", "Debian",
      "Mandriva"};

  auto *hbox = new QHBoxLayout(this);

  combo = new QComboBox();
  combo->addItems(distros);

  hbox->addWidget(combo);
  hbox->addSpacing(15);

  label = new QLabel("Arch", this);
  hbox->addWidget(label);

  connect(combo, qOverload<const QString &>(&QComboBox::activated),
      label, &QLabel::setText);   // use of undeclared identifier 'qOverload'
}
```

main.cpp :

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "combobox.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  ComboBoxEx window;

  window.resize(300, 150);
  window.setWindowTitle("QComboBox");
  window.show();

  return app.exec();
}
```

This is my first question of the forum.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the qt documentation for qOverload and you might require C++ 14 and you might need to insert this in your .pro file-> CONFIG += c++14.

Reffer to the link for more details:-
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qOverload

But you can still work around this using the helper methods ,since in c++11 you can use the helper functions.
Eg:-QOverload<>::of(&Foo::overloadedFunction)

You can read more about it in the documentation.

Comment: My pleasure, I am happy giving back to the community!!

Answer (score 0):

`activated(const QString &);` marked `QT_DEPRECATED_SINCE(5, 15)` with message `Use textActivated() instead`, you dont need `qOverload<const QString &>` for `textActivated`. Also had troubles with that macro - sometimes it doesn't compile.

Comment: You're right, textActivated is a better option according to Qt's documentation. But I couldn't figure out how to use it in this example.

Comment: `connect(combo, &QComboBox::textActivated, label, &QLabel::setText);` or `connect(combo, &QComboBox::textActivated, [=](const QString& text){label->setText(text);});`

Comment: That is really elegant and truly helpful. Thank you so much.